# Script doesn't work when nickname is same as command - XChat

Tags: python, irc

I have made a script for XChat in Python. It gives a random message when someone types !pop. It works fine when my nickname is anything other than Pop. If I change the nickname to Pop it doesn't work. It only works if I type !pop.

Here is the code:

```
__module_name__ = 'Pop Script'
__module_version__ = '0.1'
__module_description__ = 'Epic popping script.'

import xchat
from random import randint

msgs = ['pops a balloon', 
        'pops a roller pop',
        'eats up a poppy pie',
        'pops a cracker',
        'pops a lollipop']

command = '!pop'

def choose_msg():
    x = randint(0,len(msgs)-1)
    message = msgs[x]
    return message

def a(word, world_eol, userdata):
    msg = choose_msg()
    cmnd = 'me %s' % msg
    if word[1] == command:
        xchat.command(cmnd)
    else:
        xchat.EAT_NONE

xchat.hook_print("Channel Message", a)
xchat.hook_print("Your Message", a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Never worked with XCHAT; however I will take a stab at this. It appears that you are comparing the command text to be exactly **!pop** instead of seeing if it contains **pop**

There are two ways of going about this:

1. From the command that is present in **word[1]** strip off the **!**
   character and compare the remaining part of the command with **pop**
   in a case in-sensitive manner
2. Alternatively check if **word[1]** contains pop. Something like
   below:

   ```
   def a(word, world_eol, userdata):
       msg = choose_msg()
       cmnd = 'me %s' % msg
       # here we normalize the input command to lower case and check if **command** is a substring of **word[1]**
       if command in word[1].lower() 
           xchat.command(cmnd)
       else:
           xchat.EAT_NONE
   ```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: can you provide details of the exact output?